# I want to make a FlatList who render all datas

Tags: reactjs, javascript-objects, array.prototype.map

But, they returns only one array !

my variable (contents of my bdd Firebase) contain this:

```js
Array [ {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { title: "boissonstitle", category: "boissons", describe: "boissonsdesc", … }
​
1: Object { title: "Oeuf en neige", category: "Desserts", describe: "Les œufs à la neige sont un entremets ou dessert de la cuisine française composé de blancs d'œufs sucrés, fouettés, pochés ou cuits au bain-marie, accompagnés d'une crème anglaise et généralement nappés de caramel", … }
​
2: Object { category: "Entrées", describe: "Entréesdesc", title: "Entréestitle", … }
​
3: Object { title: "repastitle", category: "repas", describe: "repasdesc", … }
​
length: 4
```

Ensuite, enfin, after that i make this:

```js
return (
        <div className="container-fluid css-selector m-0 p-0" style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
            <div>
                {products ? (
                    products.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                {/* Liste d'items à afficher  */}
                                <FlatList data={item} plainList={true} list={item} />
                                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                                <h2>{item.describe}</h2>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                ) : (
                    <h1>Hi</h1>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

but they return only one object, why they doesn't iterate on all objects ?

This my entire code:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';
import FlatList from 'flatlist-react';
import Empty from './Empty';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp({
    // Myconfig
});
const db = getFirestore();

const Allproducts = () => {
    const [ products, setProducts ] = useState(); // description
    const [ title, setTitle ] = useState();

    // console.log(products);

    const getUser = async () => {
        const q = query(collection(db, 'User'));
        const Array = [];
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
            Array.push(doc.data());
            setProducts(Array);
        });
    };

    console.log(products);

    useEffect(() => {
        getUser();
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid css-selector m-0 p-0" style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
            <div>
                {products ? (
                    products.map((item) => {
                        return (
                            <div>
                                {/* Liste d'items à afficher  */}
                                <FlatList data={item} plainList={true} list={item} />
                                <h2>{item.title}</h2>
                                <h2>{item.describe}</h2>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                ) : (
                    <h1>Hi</h1>
                )}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Allproducts;
```

Comment: According to the FlatList documentation you need to pass the `renderItem` property, which is function that renders individual item: `renderItem={your_func}`

Answer (score 1):

#### What's the problem ?

You don't use FlatList correctly. The doc says this :

> FlatList has two required props, **list** and **renderItem**.

In your code, you try to write a list inside a list. Hello inception !

**AND** you forget the renderItem prop.

#### How to solve that ?

```js
import FlatList, { PlainList } from 'flatlist-react'

const Allproducts = () => {
   const list = [
     { title: "Harry Potter 1", description: "Tome 1" },
     { title: "Harry Potter 2", description: "Tome 2" },
   ];

   function renderedItem(item, index) {
      // Destructurate each item
      const { title, description } = item;

      // Don't forget key prop on each items
      return (
         <div key={index}>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
            <h2>{description}</h2>
         </div>
      );
   } 

   return (
      <PlainList
         list={list}
         renderItem={renderedItem}
      />
   );
}
```

#### Explanation

- First you have an item called list, FlatList will going to iterate on him.
- Second you have a function called renderedItem, that's will explain to FlatList how to render each item in your list.
- It's important to attribute a unique key prop in react list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in step `getUser` async function.

Here you make a loop and updating your state at each turn of the loop with `setProducts`.

You have to take **setProducts out of the loop** and it should work:

```js
const getUser = async () => {
   const q = query(collection(db, 'User'));
   // Here it's better in lowercase Array > array
   const array = [];
   const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
   querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const { title, describe, image, category } = doc.data();
      array.push({
         id: doc.id,
         title,
         describe,
         image,
         category
      });
   });
   setProducts(Array)
};
```

I also think that **you can do without PlainList** :

```js
{products ? (products.map((item, index) => {
      const { id, describe, title } = item;
      return (
         <div key={index}>
            <h2>{id}</h2>
            <h2>{describe}</h2>
            <h2>{title}</h2>
         </div>
      );
   })) : (
      <Empty />
   )
}
```